# Understanding a ArrayList of references

Tags: java

When we create ArrayList such

```
 ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
```

We are creating a ArrayList of type String and a reference to this object by the name obj. What about this?

```
 ArrayList<Node> obj;
```

A ArrayList of type Node with only the reference that is pointing to null? What does this statement look like in memory?

**Example:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class PackageNode {

private String value;

private List<PackageNode> children;

public PackageNode(String value) {

this.value = value;

}

public String getValue() {

return value;

}

public void setValue(String value) {

this.value = value;

}

public List<PackageNode> getChildren() {

return children;

}

public void setChildren(List<PackageNode> children) {

this.children = children;

}


}
```

Assume the code above is a Node class for a PackageTree, What does this mean?

```
List<PackageNode> children;
```

Comment: Depends if it's class or method .

Comment: Node is a class...!

Comment: That's irrelevant. Where is the variable declared?

Comment: See the edit...

Comment: If it's declared at the class level, it will be null by default.

Comment: That's pointing out the obvious!! The question is what's inside each index of this ArrayList!

Comment: What are you talking about? Null means there is no ArrayList.

Comment: I'll wait for someone else to answer this, if there is anyone.

Comment: The question has already been closed. Good luck.

Comment: @Armin this declares a variable. Since the variable is an instance variable Java initializes this variable to null. A null list means "absence of list" (you should know that before even thinking about using generics). So you don't have any list. So the list can't contain anything, since there is no list.

Comment: I suppose that's what I was looking for,

Comment: That's what shmosel already told you, but you disregarded his comment.

Comment: What different is between Node next, and List<Node> next? I understand they are pointing to null, whats their difference ?

Comment: The same difference between a variable than can reference an egg, and a variable that can reference a box that can contain eggs.

Comment: Thats what i was looking for. Thank you.